# Type safety when optional field is guaranteed to be present

Tags: scala, design-patterns, types

Let's say I have a following case class:

```
case class Product(name: String, categoryId: Option[Long]/*, other fields....*/)
```

Here you can see that `categoryId` is optional.

Now let's say I have a following method in my DAO layer:

```
getCategoryProducts(): List[Product] = {
    // query products that have categoryId defined
}
```

You see, that this method returns products, that are `guaranteed` to have categoryId defined with some value.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
trait HasCategory {
    def categoryId_!: Long
}
// and then specify in method signature
getCategoryProducts(): List[Product with HasCategory]
```

This will work, but then such a product will have two methods: `categoryId_!` and `categoryId` that smells bad.

Another way would be:

```
sealed trait Product {
    def name: String
    /*other fields*/
}
case class SimpleProduct(name: String, /*, other fields....*/) extends Product 
case class ProductWithCategory(name: String, categoryId: Long/*, other fields....*/) extends Product 
def getCategoryProducts: List[ProductWithCategory] = ...
```

This method helps to avoid duplicate methods categoryId and categoryId_!, but it requires you to create two case classes and a trait duplicating all the fields, which also smells.

My question: how can I use Scala type system to declare this specific case without these fields duplications ?

Comment: First of all.... What's wrong with `Option[ Long ]` ? But if you want then you can define an implicit TypeClass `ProductWithAssuredCategoryId`. Supply your extra methods with this one.

Comment: In case you don't understand TypeClasses yet, you can ask for an example.

Comment: Callers of DAO expect products to have categoryId and it doesn't have any sense for them to do something if it's None. But it also smells if they just  do `product.categoryId.get`

Comment: Having two methods doesn't smell bad, the weird naming convention (`_!`) does. Why not call them `categoryIdOption` and `categoryId`?

Comment: @curious yes I know how to filter by option, thanks. But it's not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it is to use type classes -

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object Example {

  sealed class CartId[T]

  implicit object CartIdSomeWitness extends CartId[Some[Long]]
  implicit object CartIdNoneWitness extends CartId[None.type]
  implicit object CartIdPresentWitness extends CartId[Long]

  case class Product[T: CartId](name: String, categoryId: T /*, other fields....*/)

  val id: Long = 7

  val withId = Product("dsds", id)
  val withSomeId = Product("dsds", Some(id))
  val withNoneId = Product("dsds", None)

  val presentId: Long = withId.categoryId
  val maybeId: Some[Long] = withSomeId.categoryId
  val noneId: None.type = withNoneId.categoryId

  val p = Product("sasa", true) //Error:(30, 18) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type com.novak.Program.CartId[Boolean]
}
```

This solution involves some code and dependent on implicits but does what you're trying to achieve.
Be aware that this solution is not completely sealed and can be 'hacked'. You can cheat and do something like -

```
  val hack: Product[Boolean] = Product("a", true)(new CartId[Boolean])
  val b: Boolean =hack.categoryId
```

For some more - advanced solutions which include 
* Miles Sabin (@milessabin)’s Unboxed union types in Scala via the Curry-Howard isomorphism
* Scalaz / operator
http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Coproducts.html

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much this will scale for your particular case, but one solution that comes to mind is to parameterize over the `Option` type using a higher-kinded generic type:

```
object Example {
  import scala.language.higherKinds

  type Id[A] = A

  case class Product[C[_]](name: String, category: C[Long])

  def productsWithoutCategories: List[Product[Option]] = ???

  def productsWithCategories: List[Product[Id]] = ???
}
```

Comment: How can I get List[Product] with this ? Could you please show in example.

Comment: @Oleksandr.Bezhan sorry, I had a mistake in the snippet. The case class was supposed to be `Product`, not `Category`. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @Ionut Yes, now it's clear. It makes what I asked for, but seems pretty complex and not as readable as other solutions. I would rather choose duplication and readability over complexity. But if no one provides better solution I will tag this as correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can suggest how to improve readability here ? Because now if you find somewhere in project code `def f(product: Product[Id])` it's not obvious what the argument's type means.

Comment: @Oleksandr.Bezhan hmm, I guess you can introduce some further type aliases, such as `type CategorizedProduct = Product[Id]`. Then you'd have a `List[CategorizedProduct]`. Not sure what alias to use for `Product[Option]` though.